# Spring Security 3 Custom Filter and URL Patterns

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have configured a custom Pre Auth filter that extends `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`.

From my understanding, I can specify which URL patterns utilize this filter, and specify any URLs that I do not want to use any filters or security on.

I am using Spring Security 3.2 and the XML configuration, therefore I thought something like this should work.

```
<security:http pattern="/login" use-expressions="true" security="none">
    </security:http>


<security:http pattern="/home" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"
        entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
            ref="openTokenFilter" />
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/> 
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </security:http>
```

By specifying `security="none"` for the `pattern="/login"`, I thought that this would not call the filter when accessing "localhost:8080/login" for example. However, it is still calling the filter.

The filter seems to have some global setting where it is called for every request. I am using Spring Boot so I do not have a web.xml file or any custom servlet configurations.

Basically, I want the filter to work for every URL except '/login'.

Comment: Does your login page have an extension? in this case use pattern /login*

Comment: It is just a simple html file, I tried this but unfortunately didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The following sentences are quoted from spring doc:

> To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to
>   set the use-expressions attribute in the `<http>` element to true.
>   **Spring Security will then expect the access** attributes of the `<intercept-url>` elements to contain **Spring EL expressions**. The
>   expressions should evaluate to a boolean, defining whether access
>   should be allowed or not

So you should delete use-expressions="true" and use pattern="/login*".